# small difference on offsets

Tags: javascript, jquery, positioning, offset

I have this layout built that has a section which should work as side-by-side vertical slider. It works fine, except for the small difference betwen slide offsets.

I have a script that calculates top position of each slide and it gives exactly same positions to each slide, which is also right.

Whats wrong then? When my scroll even ticks and slides scroll, they wont scroll to right positions. I can't resolve what causes this - could you?

Could it be the way I detect top positions of each slide? I just dont think so, because there's no gap between them. Anyway, this is how I detect "the tops"

```
  function getPanelOffsets(elem, array){
    var top = 0;
    $(elem).each(function(key,value){     
      if(key === 0){
        top = 0;
      }else{
        top = array[key-1] + $(this).height();
      }
      array.push(top);
    });
    console.log(array);
  }
  getPanelOffsets(".left article",leftPanelOffsets);
  getPanelOffsets(".right article",rightPanelOffsets);
```

[**CODE HERE**](http://codepen.io/virmasalo/pen/zBmGXw?editors=0010)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found it!

It was HTML/CSS problem. HTML structure of my slides was like this:

```
<article>
 <header>
 </header>
 <div class="article-content">
   <h1>This is article</h1>
 </div>
</article>
```

`<h1>` had a margin top, which pushed the whole container down and messed up the offset calclulations.

Well done mate! * Tapping my shoulder *